# SAS create column based on comparing others

Tags: sas

I have following data:

```
data temp;
input id int1 int2 char1$ char2$;
cards;
1 2 3 AA BB
2 3 3 AB CC
3 4 5 AC DD
4 5 5 AD AD
5 6 7 AE FF
6 7 8 AF GG
;
run;
```

I want create a new column "difference" which is the result of comparing int1 to int2 and char1 to char2, "difference" is incremental in function of dissimilarities :

- if int1 = int2 and  char1 = char2: difference = 0
- if int1 ^= int2 and  char1 = char2: difference = 1
- if int1 ^= int2 and  char1 ^= char2: difference = 2
  ...

I want a result like this:

```
data result;
input id int1 int2 char1$ char2$ differences;
cards;
1 2 3 AA BB 2
2 3 3 AB CC 1
3 4 5 AC DD 2
4 5 5 AD AD 0
5 6 7 AE FF 2
6 7 8 AF GG 2
;
run;
```

In that example, there are only 4 columns but I had 36 columns in original Data.
I start trying with a loop, I don't know if it's the correct way to solve the pb:

```
data result;
    SET temp;
    array id int1 int2 char1 char2;

    DO i = 1 to dim(id);
        DIFFERENCE = 0;
        if int1           ^= int2           THEN DIFFERENCE = DIFFERENCE + 1;
        if char1         ^= char2         THEN DIFFERENCE = DIFFERENCE + 1;

    END;
RUN;
```

but it doesn't work , do you have an idea?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you repeatedly setting difference to zero?  Move that initialization assignment before the DO loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your result table I speculate that the difference shall be equal to 1 also when `int1 = int2 and char1 != char2`.

In that scenario, a simple use of the [IFN()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n0l3n5z2h31h7wn1fmnqd33ibhap.htm) function should output the desired result.

```
data result;
    set temp;
    difference = ifn(int1=int2 and char1=char2, 0, ifn((int1 ne int2 and char1 = char2) or (int1 = int2 and char1 ne char2), 1, 2));
run;
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: After DD Chen comment**

```
data result;
    set temp;
    do i=1 to _n_;
        difference = 0;
        if int1 ne int2 then difference + 1;
        if char1 ne char2 then difference + 1;
        /* add all comparison statements ... */
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but in original data I need to make many comparaisons, so I prefer that "difference" increase in function of dissimilarities.

Comment: Then please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If difference is incremental, its maximum value can only be 2 for that particular example.

Comment: ok, I re-edit my post and specify the point.

Comment: Edited my answer. The variable difference is incremented. Note that if the column names you are comparing are sharing similar patterns, there are better ways than to list them in x if statements.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! yeah, They do, I have to compare variable_1_2019 ... variable_n_2019 to variable_1_2020 ... variable_n_2020. what's your advises?

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at the two different answers in [Dividing multiple columns dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822296/dividing-multiple-columns-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

SAS will evaluate a boolean expression to 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE).

So to get your output you just need to do:

```
data want;
  set temp;
  difference = (int1 ne int2) + (char1 ne char2);
run;
```